# Adding condition (string) to Entity LINQ query

Tags: c#, string, linq, entity-framework, select

This is how i use linq with my entity. All i want to do is to be able to add condition dinamically. I have conditions in string. For example `notes == 'some words'` or `DokumentID == 4`. I would love to use that somehow as condition in linQ. I can provide the name of column in database and value searched in two different string. But still i don't have idea how to add it to my linq. 
Here is my code from program:

```
        ListImport.Clear();
        using (var db = new Minorlex_MPIPSEntities())
        {

            var query = from s in db.tbl_Dokumenty
                        where s.IdDokumentu == 15
                        select s;

            foreach (tbl_Dokumenty Dokument in query)
            {
                ListImport.Add(Dokument);
            }
        }
```

and i want to try if i can take the variable string and use it like status in here. To use a variable in string and provide it to linq with added condition to it.

`query.Where(x => x.status < 0);`

Comment: Can you break out the column name and column value into separate ops or are they always coming in as a single string?

Comment: they are separate actually. Column name and value are in 2 different strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with Dynamic LINQ.

Just `Install-Package System.Linq.Dynamic`, include the `System.Linq.Dynamic` namespace, and you'll have versions of the LINQ methods (Where, OrderBy, etc) that take strings and parse them.

Answer (score 0):

for dynamic condition you can use following changes in code

```
   ListImport.Clear();
    using (var db = new Minorlex_MPIPSEntities())
    {

        var query = from s in db.tbl_Dokumenty
                    where s.IdDokumentu == 15 || s.DynamicCondition
                    select s;

        foreach (tbl_Dokumenty Dokument in query)
        {
            ListImport.Add(Dokument);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need more control, this is what I've just came up with:

```
private IList<TEntity> Condition<TEntity, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> propertySelector, TProperty propertyValue)
        where TEntity :class 
    {
        PropertyInfo property = (PropertyInfo)((MemberExpression)propertySelector.Body).Member;
        ParameterExpression typeParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity));

        MemberExpression propertyExpression = Expression.Property(typeParameter, property);

        using (Minorlex_MPIPSEntities entities = new Minorlex_MPIPSEntities())
        {

            BinaryExpression criteriaExpression = 
                Expression.Equal(propertyExpression, Expression.Constant(propertyValue));

            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> condition = 
                Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(criteriaExpression, typeParameter);

            IEnumerable<TEntity> query = entities.Set<TEntity>().Where(condition);

            return query.ToList();
        }
    }
```

just pass a property selector expression and a value.
you may extend the method with custom set of operations(now there's simple equality, see `criteriaExpression`)